# How to query data from mongodb collection by just the first 3 numbers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, mean-stack, export-to-csv

I have a collection in my mongodb that is called pnumber and looks like this when I do db.pnumber.find() mongo shell

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57696e03b9c614e1143c759e"), "pnumber" : NumberLong("5037816575") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57696e03b9c614e1143c759f"), "pnumber" : NumberLong("5087368074") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57696e03b9c614e1143c75a0"), "pnumber" : NumberLong("8055019263") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57696e03b9c614e1143c75a1"), "pnumber" : NumberLong("2153334813") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57696e03b9c614e1143c75a2"), "pnumber" : NumberLong("5592842086") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57696e03b9c614e1143c75a3"), "pnumber" : NumberLong("4356696916") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57696e03b9c614e1143c75a4"), "pnumber" : NumberLong("9545935012") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57696e03b9c614e1143c75a5"), "pnumber" : NumberLong("8083661362") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57696e03b9c614e1143c75a6"), "pnumber" : NumberLong("6065240853") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57696e03b9c614e1143c75a7"), "pnumber" : NumberLong("4236768328") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57696e03b9c614e1143c75a8"), "pnumber" : NumberLong("9705354839") }
```

I am using a mean stack application that is connected to this database through mongoose.

I would like to have an input field with a search button that when a user enters the area code that a list pops up from the collection of all the entry's that match that area code and have a download button that creates a csv with all of those entries.

I have:

```
var csv = require('express-csv');
```

in my app.js file.

Any info would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.pnumber.find( { pnumber: /^123/ } )
```

this results with all response that start with the value 123.
if you tie the form with this, the response should be the results you are looking for.

Comment: This works I had to rebuild the database and import using a .json file in the format of: { "phoneNumbers": "5082720945" } per record in order for your query to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to match strings, use **$regex** operator

```
db.getCollection('blah').find({'phoneNumber':{'$regex': /^phoneNumber/}})
```

if you would like to match numbers, use **$where** operator.

```
db.getCollection('blah').find({$where: "/^970*/.test(this.phoneNumber)"})
```

Comment: This works but only displays 1 - 3 results at a time.

Comment: i don't see any artificial limitations on returned result size. 
I think 1-3 results is all that matched

Comment: I did a search for 954 area codes in sublime text and there was 22 of them that I counted with 954 as an area code